# How to link libraries when internally linked libraries share the same function names?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

My program `my_program` uses function `funA()` from package_1(nvidia's jetson_multimedia_api) present in say `lib_1` and `funB()` from package_2(opencv 4.4) present in say `lib_2`. Both of these packages are black box** for me.

`funA()` and `funB()` are different but internally `funA()` present in `lib_1` relies on `*libnvjpeg.so*` and `funB()` present in `lib_2` relies on `libjpeg.so`.  The libraries `*libnvjpeg.so*` and `libjpeg.so` share same function names(`*libnvjpeg.so*` is a modified version of `libjpeg.so` to utilise hardware acceleration).

So `funA()` which needs to call upon `*libnvjpeg.so*` may call upon `libjpeg.so` and vice-versa (which basically depends on which lib is loaded first if I'm not incorrect).
How do I ensure that `funA()` calls upon `*libnvjpeg.so*` only (and vice-versa)?
Everything is in c++.

(** they are not perfect black box. opencv is opensource and if required I could rebuild it and I have some control over `lib_1` but have no control over libraries 'lib_1' depends on , eg. `*libnvjpeg.so*`)

---

I thought since `*libnvjpeg.so*` is a modified version of `libjpeg.so`, it could be used everywhere. So I controlled which lib is loaded first using `LD_PRELOAD` but that didn't work and program crashed when `funB()` needed `libjpeg.so`.For this reason, I think rebuilding opencv to use `*libnvjpeg.so*` instead of `libjpeg.so` will also not work.

Comment: It would be bad if calls to the libraries were intermixed because they may have incompatible e.g. structure definitions. That would explain a crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dynamically load at least one of the libraries.

Windows has a similar feature I can't remember the name of.

Under Linux, BSD & al., you can use [`dlmopen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html):

> dlmopen()
>
> The dlmopen() function differs from dlopen() primarily in that it
> accepts an additional argument, lmid, that specifies the link-map
> list (also referred to as a namespace) in which the shared object
> should be loaded.  (By comparison, dlopen() adds the dynamically
> loaded shared object to the same namespace as the shared object
> from which the dlopen() call is made.)

> dlmopen() and namespaces
>
> A link-map list defines an isolated namespace for the resolution
> of symbols by the dynamic linker.  Within a namespace, dependent
> shared objects are implicitly loaded according to the usual
> rules, and symbol references are likewise resolved according to
> the usual rules, but such resolution is confined to the
> definitions provided by the objects that have been (explicitly
> and implicitly) loaded into the namespace.

Comment: does that mean I can't link those libraries during the compile time? if so, won't the compiler complain about missing functions etc?
Or can I compile the program as I have and again dynamically load the libraries and get pointer to by function from there?

Comment: This is all dynamic/run-time linking.